# Hadoop map task initialization takes too long

Tags: hadoop

Well, lately, in any Hadoop flow I'm running, I encounter a 3 minutes, 10 second delay for a certain map node (master working as slave). After that initialization delay, it goes back to normal and executes instantly.

For example, when running QuasiMonteCarlo example:

```
Task Id                                 Start Time  Finish Time <br>
attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0    10/04 20:14:54  10/04 20:18:05 (3mins, 10sec)   /default-rack/master

2012-04-10 20:18:04,470 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library<br>2012-04-10 20:18:04,646 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=MAP, sessionId=<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,647 WARN org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,751 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,754 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@79ee2c2c<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600<br>
2012-04-10 20:18<br>:04,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
2012-04-10 20:18:04,939 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,940 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,940 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 18; bufvoid = 104857600<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,940 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214392(104857568); length = 5/6553600<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,975 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:05,058 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0' done.<br>
```

Task tracker log is more telling:

```
2012-04-10 **20:14:54,615** INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 1 and trying to launch attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0 which needs 1 slots<br>
2012-04-10 20:14:54,685 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner jvm_201204101957_0006_m_377512887 spawned.<br>
2012-04-10 20:16:34,041 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 1<br>
2012-04-10 **20:18:04,433** INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201204101957_0006_m_377512887 given task: attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0<br>
2012-04-10 20:18:04,938 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0 0.0% <br>
2012-04-10 20:18:05,056 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0 0.667% Generated 1000 samples. <br>
```

> sort
>   2012-04-10 20:18:05,058 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0 is done.
>   2012-04-10 20:18:05,058 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0  was 28
>   2012-04-10 20:18:05,058 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
>   2012-04-10 20:18:05,213 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ProcessTree: Sending signal to all members of process group -23030: SIGTERM. Exit code 1
>   2012-04-10 20:18:08,478 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Sent out 28 bytes to reduce 0 from map: attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0 given 28/24
>   2012-04-10 20:18:08,478 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Shuffled 1maps (mapIds=attempt_201204101957_0006_m_000003_0) to reduce 0 in 29s
>   2012-04-10 20:18:08,478 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.clienttrace: src: 147.102.7.173:50060, dest: 147.102.7.175:57289, maps: 1, op: MAPRED_SHUFFLE, reduceID: 0, duration: 29
>   2012-04-10 20:18:10,217 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201204101957_0006_m_377512887 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1

I suspect a network issue here, but I can ping and ssh with no problem.

Comment: `master as a slave` - are you running a task tracker and name node alongside each other (on the same node). Also you log file shows a start-to-end time of just over 1/2 a second. What does the tasktracker logs for the node say?

Comment: Updated the Question<br>

I have a total of three nodes, master is both jobtracker/namenode/datanode.
The problem is the initialization which takes more than it should be, as shown at the logs in the Question.

Could it be a JVM thing, should I get a stack trace as well?

Comment: And which version of hadoop are you using?